# Parse an incorrectly delimited text file using pandas

Tags: python, parsing, pandas

I would like to parse the file listed below into a pandas dataframe with year and month as a datetime index and the remaining 11 columns into dataframe columns.

```
 STANDARDIZED NORTHERN HEMISPHERE TELECONNECTION INDICES (1981-2010 Clim)

column 1: Year (yy)
column 2: Month (mm)
column 3: North Atlantic Oscillation (NAO)
column 4: East Atlantic Pattern (EA)
column 5: West Pacific Pattern (WP)
column 6: EastPacific/ North Pacific Pattern (EP/NP)
column 7: Pacific/ North American Pattern (PNA)
column 8: East Atlantic/West Russia Pattern (EA/WR)
column 9: Scandinavia Pattern (SCA)
column 10: Tropical/ Northern Hemisphere Pattern (TNH)
column 11: Polar/ Eurasia Pattern (POL)
column 12: Pacific Transition Pattern (PT)
column 13: Explained Variance (%) of leading 10 modes
PATTERN VALUES ARE SET TO -99.9 FOR MONTHS IN WHICH THE PATTERN IS NOT A LEADING MODE

yyyy mm   NAO   EA    WP   EP/NP  PNA  EA/WR  SCA   TNH   POL  PT    Expl. Var.

1950  1   0.56 -2.71 -1.69  0.91 -3.65  2.29  0.78  0.55 -0.71-99.90   86.0
1950  2   0.01  0.66 -1.36 -1.13 -1.69 -0.57 -0.94 -1.07  1.25-99.90   58.6
1950  3  -0.78  0.82 -0.38 -0.02 -0.06 -1.80 -0.22-99.90  0.78-99.90   54.3
1950  4   0.65  0.28 -0.50 -1.87 -0.23 -2.50  0.46-99.90  0.10-99.90   64.8
1950  5  -0.50 -0.51  0.23 -0.98 -0.40  1.41  0.28-99.90  0.55-99.90   49.6
```

I have read in the file, filename using pandas command below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[[0, 1]], skiprows=17)
```

A snippet of the output:

```
             NAO    EA           WP  EP/NP   PNA  EA/WR          SCA  \
yyyy_mm                                                                
1950-01-01  0.56 -2.71        -1.69   0.91 -3.65   2.29         0.78   
1950-02-01  0.01  0.66        -1.36  -1.13 -1.69  -0.57        -0.94   
1950-03-01 -0.78  0.82        -0.38  -0.02 -0.06  -1.80  -0.22-99.90   
1950-04-01  0.65  0.28        -0.50  -1.87 -0.23  -2.50   0.46-99.90   
1950-05-01 -0.50 -0.51         0.23  -0.98 -0.40   1.41   0.28-99.90
```

While I am able to parse most of the data correctly, the `-99.90` data values don't seem to be delimited from the previous value and thus get lumped into the previous columns. I assume these values are flagged anyhow, so I would be happy to omit them from the resulting dataframe.

I have used `na_values` kwarg, but that doesn't have an effect.

If there is a built in solution to this problem, or would I need to write a custom text parser in front of the pandas parsing? If a custom parser is needed, what is the most direct way to eliminate/replace the `-99.90` values prior to pandas parsing so that the resulting data frame is parsed correctly?

Comment: try to use [read_fwf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) instead of `read_csv()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the header by hand and specifying the widths works:

```
with open(filename) as fobj:
    for _ in range(17):
        fobj.readline()
    names = fobj.readline().split()
    names = names[:-2] + [' '.join(names[-2:]) ]
    fobj.readline()
    widths = [4, 3, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
    df = pd.read_fwf(fobj, widths=widths, names=names, index_col=False)
```

Result:

```
   yyyy  mm   NAO    EA    WP  EP/NP   PNA  EA/WR   SCA    TNH   POL    PT  Expl. Var.
0  1950   1  0.56 -2.71 -1.69   0.91 -3.65   2.29  0.78   0.55 -0.71 -99.9       86.0
1  1950   2  0.01  0.66 -1.36  -1.13 -1.69  -0.57 -0.94  -1.07  1.25 -99.9       58.0
2  1950   3 -0.78  0.82 -0.38  -0.02 -0.06  -1.80 -0.22 -99.90  0.78 -99.9       54.0
3  1950   4  0.65  0.28 -0.50  -1.87 -0.23  -2.50  0.46 -99.90  0.10 -99.9       64.0
4  1950   5 -0.50 -0.51  0.23  -0.98 -0.40   1.41  0.28 -99.90  0.55 -99.9       49.0
```